# matlab inline function with special handling for zero

Tags: function, matlab, inline

I have a function that has a singularity at zero. The resulting value should be at that point 1.

However I fails to understand how to create an inline function that has a special treatment for values of x and y at x or y = 0.

The function could for example be

```
f = @(x,y) ( 1./x + 1./y );
```

Comment: you can create your own `iif` function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question with a counter-question: why do you want it to be inline?

As a general rule, keep inline functions simple. If more functionality is needed, use a dedicated function:

```
function val = f(x,y)

    if ~all(size(x)==size(y))
        error('sizes must match');

    val = zeros(size(x));

    zero_x = x==0;
    zero_y = y==0;

    not_zero = ~zero_x & ~zero_y;
    zero = ~not_zero;

    val(not_zero) = 1./x(not_zero) + 1./y(not_zero);
    val(zero) = 1;           

end
```

Having said that, there *are* of course ways to do it inline (see other answers).

But as you indicated, your actual function is more complex, so...why inline?

Answer (score 2):

As *dirty* trick you could replace x with `x + (x==0)`

Then if x equals zero you would have 0+1 in the denominator.

---

In some cases you could also abuse operators that "short circuit".

Like `~isfinite(f(x)) || f(x)`

Comment: It is too dirty, my actual function is much more complex. It should be more like an conditional in a function.

Comment: I suppose you fare better with the iif. But I just added another dirty trick to my post - in case you really don't want iif :)

Answer (score 2):

Create the following `iif.m` function file, residing in your working folder, or even as a subfunction if you're using it in other functions (scripts of course can not contain subfunctions):

```
function val = iif(expr, truepart, falsepart)
    if isscalar(truepart)
        truepart=truepart(ones(size(expr)));
    end
    if isscalar(falsepart)
       falsepart=falsepart(ones(size(expr))); 
    end
    val = arrayfun(@iif_scalar, expr, truepart, falsepart);
end
function val = iif_scalar(expr,truepart,falsepart)
    if expr
        val = truepart;
    else
        val = falsepart;
    end
end
```

and use it as follows:

```
f = @(x,y) iif(x==0 | y==0, 1, 1./x + 1./y );
```

I kept the `iif` function as general as possible, you can use it on vectors, scalars, mixed scalar and vectors, or even matrices. For example, in the above I used 2 vectors and a scalar:

```
iif( ...
     x==0 | y==0 ,... % expression if x or y are 0 => vector
     1 , ...          % scalar obviously
     1./x + 1./y ...  % function of x and y => vector
   )
```

Comment: Why not implement the whole thing as `expr.*truepart + ~expr.*falsepart`? You don't need two separate functions, rescaling, `arrayfun`, etc...

Comment: In the general case, the return value can be everything, not necessarily a number, for example a char array. For OP this technique might work however.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - completely WRONG. In the example given, the actual function returns an inf at zero, but 0*inf==NaN. So your example would return NaN at zero, not the desired value of 1. Try out your suggestions if you don't know they work.

Comment: @woodchips no need for arrogance or aggression -- please give a working alternative that is better than mine, and shorter/faster than the `iif()` above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is roughly what most people would want in this case.

```
1+sum([repmat(nan,~**0**,1) 0])
```

ans =
   NaN

```
1+sum([repmat(nan,~**1**,1) 0])
```

ans =
   1

Now generalizing:

```
zero2nanElseNum_inline = @(x) x*(1+sum([repmat(nan,~x,1) 0]))
```

---

```
zero2nanElseNum_inline(0)
```

ans =
   NaN

```
zero2nanElseNum_inline(10)
```

ans =
   10

```
zero2nanElseNum_inline(1)
```

ans =
   1

---

For the specific case at hand, you could simply take the code snippet:

```
sum([repmat(nan,~**0**,1) 0])
```

feed it in to isnan:

```
isnan(sum([repmat(nan,~**0**,1) 0]))
```

and add the result to your original number.